# Error when trying to view the Service.cs in browser and using this activity

Tags: c#, ms-access

I always get this error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

This is my C# code:

```
[WebMethod]
public string AddNews(string time1, string content,string topic)
{
    string strSql = String.Format("insert into [News] ([time],[content],[topic]) values (" + time1 + " , " + content + " , " + topic + " )");
    DAL.ChangeTable(strSql);
    return "News added Successfully";
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use [SQL Parameter](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)

And add ' in strings

```
string strSql = String.Format("INSERT INTO [News] ([time], [content], [topic]) VALUES ('" + time1 + "' , '" + content + "' , '" + topic + "' )");
```

Comment: thank you !
that was part of my problem the message was showing because I was entering the wrong form of the time.

Comment: why is this answer downvoted for no reason? what is wrong with people?

Comment: Idk:| It's extremely helpful

Comment: While you did recommend using SQL parameters (with no reason why), the code you provided is still open to SQL injection.  That is why I down voted.

Comment: @ShaneRay primarily that is not part of his question, its about why his code was not working. I have provided link and OP if interested can search on his own. That might not be good reason to downvote

Answer (score 0):

First things first.  This code is open to SQL injection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and should not be used.  Second the message indicates you are not providing an input that is required.  I would check if there is an inner exception that has more details.